# Why are my bar chart percentages all off?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting a bar graph according to category_df below.
I am not sure how to copy in the DataFrame into SO, so I've represented it as dict.

```
category_df = {'total': {'Dance': 761,
  'Technology': 811,
  'Comics': 1072,
  'Fashion': 1136,
  'Food': 1439,
  'Photography': 1514,
  'Games': 1738,
  'Design': 1768,
  'Theater': 2492,
  'Art': 3992,
  'Publishing': 4770,
  'Music': 10913,
  'Film & Video': 13551},
 'success': {'Dance': 527,
  'Technology': 289,
  'Comics': 520,
  'Fashion': 335,
  'Food': 655,
  'Photography': 645,
  'Games': 635,
  'Design': 729,
  'Theater': 1642,
  'Art': 2106,
  'Publishing': 1671,
  'Music': 6792,
  'Film & Video': 6423},
 'no success': {'Dance': 234,
  'Technology': 522,
  'Comics': 552,
  'Fashion': 801,
  'Food': 784,
  'Photography': 869,
  'Games': 1103,
  'Design': 1039,
  'Theater': 850,
  'Art': 1886,
  'Publishing': 3099,
  'Music': 4121,
  'Film & Video': 7128}}
```

Used matplotlib to produce the horizontal bar chart.

```
plt.figure(figsize = [14,8])

for i in range(len(category_df)):
    plt.text(x=0, y=i, s=" "+str(int(category_df["success"][i]/category_df["total"][i]*100))+"%", color='white', va='center', fontweight='bold')

plt.xlabel("Number of Kickstarter Campaigns")
plt.title("Kickstarter Success Rate by Categories", fontdict = {"fontweight":"bold", "fontsize":18})

category_df["success"].plot(kind="barh", label="successful")
category_df["no success"].plot(kind="barh", left = category_df["success"], color="#87ceeb", label="unsuccessful")

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

This is the horizontal bar chart I received.

[image]

Everything seems in order except that the success percentage calculated is off.
I did a similar chart previously with different variables and did not have a problem with that.
Not sure what I did wrong here.

Comment: OP here. I apologise, I have uploaded the wrong image in the original post. I shall be making a new post for this question. If someone can let me know how to either edit or delete my post, I will be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Don't delete this post, just edit the post using the edit button below the post, or [click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63284849/edit)

Comment: Thanks @HampusLarsson! I've managed to make my edit :)

Comment: Are the percentages all off? closest to the x-axis.

Comment: Using your code I get a [different graph](https://imgur.com/a/yhcllZi), so maybe there is a difference between what was posted and what you are running?

Comment: @Tom reading your comment, i decided to execute my code again. But first, I reconstructed my DataFrame again from the dict (just in case). I've managed to get the same chart as you did now. I am not sure what the problem was, but it is at least now resolved. Thanks!